# Ajax Working only few times

Tags: jquery, ajax

when i click on navigation(home etc) its working perfectly but only 2 or three times.when i click again on he navigation the image i stop loading(not displaying).
thanks for your answers.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        $("#loading").show();
    });
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        $("#loading").fadeOut();
    });
    $("ul li a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        abc=$(this).attr("href");
        $(".right-content").load(abc);
    }); //`enter code here`
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">  

    <ul>
        <li><a href="abc.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="abc.php">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="form.php">Add Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="abc.php">Contact-Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="new_index.php">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="signup.php">Sign-Up</a></li>
        <li><a id="log" href="logout.php">
    </ul>
</div>
```

**IMG**

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none;width:69px;height:89px;border:1px solid black;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;padding:2px;">
<img src='loading.gif' width="64" height="64" /><br>Loading..</div>
```

Comment: Hello Sir,I am facing problem with this code.when i click ul li the href is occurs in a div.but after 2 to 3 click the ajax wouldnot work.:(

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed your tag properly at logout anchor. That might be causing problem;

Replace

```
<li><a id="log" href="logout.php">
```

with

```
<li><a id="log" href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
```

See working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bLUZM/

Comment: thanks for your answer.you are right but now the problem is when i click again on the navigation item.its not working.image stop loading after 2 3 times click.

Comment: haven't you seen demo?

Comment: Why are you e.preventDefault();? Remove and observe impact.

Comment: e.preventDefault(); i think it avoids to reload whole page.

Comment: the problem is when i click on the ancor tag after 2 or 3 times ..the loading image is stop working.image is loading only twice until i refresh the whole page!!! 
thanks once again

Comment: have you tried after removing e.preventDefault();? I think this might be causing issue in your case.